# Go + GoLand calling function in other file

Tags: go, goland

Directory layout:

```
~ cd $GOPATH
~ tree src/simple 
src/simple
└── main
    ├── main.go
    └── other.go
```

main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This is in main. calling somefunc...")
    somefunc()
    fmt.Println("done. bye :)")
}
```

other.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func somefunc() {
    fmt.Println("This is in somefunc in other.go")
}
```

This works fine with `go build`:

```
~ cd $GOPATH/src/simple/main/
~ go build
~ ./main
This is in main. calling somefunc...
This is in somefunc in other.go
done. bye :)
```

From within the GoLand IDE, If I run, I get:

```
main/main.go:7:2: undefined: somefunc
```

Normally, there is editor highlighting of all syntax errors. The `somefunc`  call is treated as valid syntax in the editor but when I run it doesn't work. I can even cmd-click into the function to jump to the definition.

This is with GoLand 2018.2.3 and `go version go1.11`

Comment: It's not clear how you are building the project in GoLand

Comment: Goland probably just does a `go build main.go`, thus not including your extra file.

Comment: In GoLand, right-click run. In other scenarios it definitely handles multi-file builds

Answer (score 4):

In GoLand create a Run Configuration `Run -> Edit Configurations` based on `Go Build` template and set

```
Name: Build (or whatever you like)
Run kind: Directory
Directory: /Users/gopher/go/src/simple/main/
                                      ^^^^^^
Run after build: checked
Working directory: /Users/gopher/go/src/simple
```

*Change `/Users/gopher/go/` part accordingly, to match your actual path of `$GOPATH`*

And then `Run -> Build` the project

```
This is in main. calling somefunc...
This is in somefunc in other.go
done. bye :)

Process finished with exit code 0
```